# Appending to every element an iterative expression

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
Table[n^i,{n,10},{i,10}]
```

what needs to be done so that the expression being evaluated "n^i=" will appear for every element. For instance for the 1st element it would be 1^1 =1 and for the last element it would be 10^10=100000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Table[With[{i = i, n = n}, PromptForm[Defer[n^i], n^i]], {n, 5}, {i, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{1^1 =  1, 1^2 =  1, 1^3 =  1, 1^4 =  1, 1^5 =  1}, 
>  {2^1 =  2, 2^2 =  4, 2^3 =  8, 2^4 =  16, 2^5 =  32}, 
>  {3^1 =  3, 3^2 =  9, 3^3 =  27, 3^4 =  81, 3^5 =  243},
>  {4^1 =  4, 4^2 =  16, 4^3 =  64, 4^4 =  256, 4^5 =  1024}, 
>  {5^1 =  5, 5^2 =  25, 5^3 =  125, 5^4 =  625, 5^5 =  3125}}
> ```

```
TableForm @ %
```

[image]

**Note:** `PromptForm` is still undocumented. It produces output similar to `Row` with separator `" = "`.

```
PromptForm[foo, bar]
```

[image]

```
Row[{foo, " = ", bar}]
```

[image]

***Alternative methods:***

```
TableForm @ Array[PromptForm[Defer[#^#2], #^#2] &, {5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
TableForm @ Outer[PromptForm[Defer[#^#2], #^#2] &, Range @ 5 , Range @ 5]
```

> same picture

```
TableForm @ Array[Row[{Inactivate[Power @ ##], Power @ ##}, " = "] &, {5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
TableForm @ Outer[Row[{Inactivate[Power@##], Power@##}, " = "]&, Range @ 5, Range @ 5]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Row`:

```
Grid[
  Table[
    Row[{n, "^", i, " = ", n^i}]
  ,
    {n, 10}
  ,
    {i, 10}
  ]
,
  Alignment -> "=",
  Frame -> All,
  FrameStyle -> LightGray
]
```

[image: Grid]